# React Storybook addon Knobs for editing Angular props

Tags: angular, storybook

I could not edit values of props using Knobs in Storybook using Angular 2+. Knobs Github's readme.md has following line

> Storybook Addon Knobs allow you to edit React props dynamically using the Storybook UI. You can also use Knobs as a dynamic variable inside stories in Storybook.

Does that mean it's not possible with Angular, at least for now? My code is inside index.stories.ts:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/angular';
import { boolean, number, text,  button, array, select, selectV2, color, 
object, withKnobs, withKnobsOptions} from '@storybook/addon-knobs/angular';

const stories = storiesOf('Storybook Knobs',module);
stories.addDecorator(withKnobs);  
stories.add('with knobs', () => ({ 
   props:{
        Name:text('Name', 'John'),
        age:number('Age',47)
        },
        template:`My name is ${Name}, I'm ${age} years old`          
       }) );
```

Previously, I also tried using a component rather than template but I could not change the value of props like shown [here](https://storybooks-official.netlify.com/?knob-Dollars=12.5&knob-Name=Storyteller&knob-Text=Menu%20link%20item&knob-Years%20in%20NY=9&knob-background=%23ffff00&knob-Age=70&knob-Items%5B0%5D=Laptop&knob-Items%5B1%5D=Book&knob-Items%5B2%5D=Whiskey&knob-Other%20Fruit=lime&knob-Container%20width=90&knob-Birthday=1484870400000&knob-Nice=true&knob-Styles=%7B%22border%22%3A%223px%20solid%20%23ff00ff%22%2C%22padding%22%3A%2210px%22%7D&knob-Fruit=apple&knob-Active=true&selectedKind=Addons%7CKnobs.withKnobs&selectedStory=tweaks%20static%20values&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Fstories%2Fstories-panel) and [here](https://kadira-samples.github.io/storybook-knobs-example/?knob-Disabled=true&knob-Style=%7B%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22%23FFF%22%2C%22border%22%3A%221px%20solid%20%23DDD%22%2C%22borderRadius%22%3A2%2C%22outline%22%3A0%2C%22fontSize%22%3A15%2C%22cursor%22%3A%22pointer%22%7D&knob-Label=Hello%20Button&selectedKind=Storybook%20Knobs&selectedStory=with%20a%20button&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=1&downPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs). Any links to sample or article will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a full example in the Storybook repo: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/master/examples/angular-cli/src/stories/addon-knobs.stories.ts

Also, the code you posted alone doesn't provide much context. If you could create a git repo that'd be great.

This is the example we have in our repository, please test it and if it doesn't work do not hesitate and create an issue

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/angular';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

import {
  withKnobs,
  text,
  number,
  boolean,
  array,
  select,
  color,
  date,
  button,
} from '@storybook/addon-knobs/angular';

import { SimpleKnobsComponent } from './knobs.component';
import { AllKnobsComponent } from './all-knobs.component';

storiesOf('Addon|Knobs', module)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .add('Simple', () => {
    const name = text('name', 'John Doe');
    const age = number('age', 0);
    const phoneNumber = text('phoneNumber', '555-55-55');

    return {
      moduleMetadata: {
        entryComponents: [SimpleKnobsComponent],
        declarations: [SimpleKnobsComponent],
      },
      template: `
        <h1> This is a template </h1>
        <storybook-simple-knobs-component
          [age]="age"
          [phoneNumber]="phoneNumber"
          [name]="name"
        >
        </storybook-simple-knobs-component>
      `,
      props: {
        name,
        age,
        phoneNumber,
      },
    };
  })
  .add('All knobs', () => {
    const name = text('name', 'Jane');
    const stock = number('stock', 20, {
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
      step: 5,
    });
    const fruits = {
      apples: 'Apple',
      bananas: 'Banana',
      cherries: 'Cherry',
    };
    const fruit = select('fruit', fruits, 'apple');
    const price = number('price', 2.25);

    const border = color('border', 'deeppink');
    const today = date('today', new Date('Jan 20 2017'));
    const items = array('items', ['Laptop', 'Book', 'Whiskey']);
    const nice = boolean('nice', true);
    button('Arbitrary action', action('You clicked it!'));

    return {
      component: AllKnobsComponent,
      props: {
        name,
        stock,
        fruit,
        price,
        border,
        today,
        items,
        nice,
      },
    };
  });
```

Comment: This demo should be in the demo section of the Storybook for Angular page or at least for the Addon 'knobs' as the example over there does not show how to use knobs with custom components. Thanks AlterX

Comment: Yeah, in general, we recommend looking at the examples folder for each framework. We try to keep examples of most of the features there :)

Comment: Be aware that there is currently an open bug where Knobs date will throw an error if you are also using addon-actions. see https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/5184. If you want to use Knobs date, the workaround is to not use addon-actions